# How to select distinct xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

How to take  distinct nodes list  in XML in c#

for example

```
<root>
<node1 ss="d1" ff="f1" gg="h1"/>
<node1 ss="d1" ff="f2" gg="h1"/>
<node1 ss="d1" ff="f1" gg="h1"/>
<node1 ss="d2" ff="f1" gg="h1"/>
<node1 ss="d1" ff="f1" gg="h1"/>
<node1 ss="d1" ff="f1" gg="h1"/>
<node1 ss="d2" ff="f1" gg="h1"/>
<node1 ss="d1" ff="f2" gg="h1"/>
</root>
```

in this XML i will take distinct node 
and make  this xml

```
<root>
<node1 ss="d1" ff="f1" gg="h1"/>
<node1 ss="d1" ff="f2" gg="h1"/>
<node1 ss="d2" ff="f1" gg="h1"/>
</root>
```

this xml is sample not real and i look for a solution in global mode for any struct in xml

Comment: You will have to try and explain a little more than that. Can you show us what you have tried, or some example data?

Comment: Your xml node should end with either `/>` or `</node1>`; like you are doing with `root` element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Various ways you could do that; Muenchian grouping in xslt for example. But in C#, if the xml layout is known and fixed, perhaps the easiest would be:

```
        var root = XElement.Parse(xml);
        var newRoot = new XElement("root",
            root.Elements("node1").Select(el =>
            new {
                ss = (string)el.Attribute("ss"),
                ff = (string)el.Attribute("ff"),
                gg = (string)el.Attribute("gg"),
            }).Distinct().Select(obj =>
                new XElement("node1",
                    new XAttribute("ss", obj.ss),
                    new XAttribute("ff", obj.ff),
                    new XAttribute("gg", obj.gg))));
```

If you need something more flexible, an `IEqualityComparer<XElement>` (for use with `.Distinct()`) would be more valuable.